# phonegap copy a picture from iOS photo-library

Tags: cordova

I use phonegap/cordova (3.3.0) to access the iOS camera function.
Source of the camera is set to the library, to get the library entries.
If I choose a file from the library I receive the uri, I want to use this to copy the file.

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(capSucc, capFail,{
       sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});

function capSucc(fileURI){
       cpyCtrl.copy(fileURI);
}
```

Then I try to get the file from the localFileSystem by the fileURI. I receive a fileEntry, but it stops at the copy instruction of this file:

```js
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(sourceFile, onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(fileEntry) {
   var root = localStorage.rootPath;     //root : /Users/xcode/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/2102E3A0-7F22-4C56-A693-EF3CF2A7620F/Documents/
   var parentName = root.substring(root.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   var parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName,root);
   fileEntry.copy(parentEntry, "myPic.jpg", succ, fail);    //this is where the problem occurs
   }

   function succ(entry){
        alert("copy");
   }

   function fail(message){
        alert("fail");
   }

   function onError(message){
        alert("fileFail");
   }
}
```

The destination of the file should be the rootPath of the fileSystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The function has a typo. 
 I had to change

```js
fileEntry.copy(parentEntry, "myPic.jpg", succ, fail);    //this is where the problem occurs
```

to

```
fileEntry.copyTo...
```

Stupid mistake, didn't see it. Now I can copy files from the camera library in other directories.

Comment: Hi @marcel can you please post also your plugins preference versions. i'm still not enable to do that. I need your help. Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Full example for future reference anyone who might need it.

```
var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

navigator.camera.getPicture(
function(imageURI) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function fileEntrySuccess(fileEntry) {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function directoryEntrySuccess(directoryEntry) {
            var d = new Date();
            var uniqueNewFilename = Date.parse(d) + ".jpg";
            fileEntry.moveTo(directoryEntry.root, uniqueNewFilename, function moveFileSuccess(newFileEntry) {
                var picPath = newFileEntry.fullPath;
                navigator.camera.cleanup(function(){}, function(){});
            }, function(){});
        }, function(){});
    }, function(){});
}, function(message) {
    navigator.notification.alert(message, function(){}, 'Picture Not Added');
}, {
    quality: 49,
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
});
```